# Integrating Spree with an existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I've been looking for the answer of this question, and I've haven't found anything.

Is it possible to integrate spree with my own database? Or it's better to work doing extensions(what I've found)?

I have my rails app with only the scaffoldings and the migrations of my database, so, can I put my database model and spree to work together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spree is a rails engine, so it is designed to be able to integrate in to an existing site with an existing database.  Spree's database tables are all namespaced with a spree_ prefix, so you shouldn't run in to any collisions with table names.

Comment: But, maybe it's a lot of work to do this isn't it?, I mean for example I'm still struggling to add fields to the spree signup form. Also I'm not sure that if I have to work with my own User or if Spree converts my user model in an Spree user.

Comment: Spree will use the user model defined by Spree.user_class in your application.  The complexity of integrating Spree in to your existing application will depend upon the complexity of your existing application, and how tightly you want the integration to be.